# Azure Devops release pipeline deployment count for each stage

Tags: powershell, azure-devops, azure-devops-rest-api

I have written s PowerShell script to write successful and failed deployment count onto excel sheet from azure DevOps release pipeline each release stage for 2 weeks of data. My script is not returning any data, please help..

```
# Set the Azure DevOps organization and project name
$orgName = "<org-name>"
$projectName = "<project-name>"

# Set the Azure DevOps release pipeline ID and stage names
$pipelineId = <pipeline-id>                       
$stageNames = @("<stage-name-1>", "<stage-name-2>", "<stage-name-3>")

# Set the Azure DevOps PAT and base URL
$pat = "<personal-access-token>"
$baseUrl = "https://dev.azure.com/$orgName/$projectName"

# Set the date range for the query
$startDate = (Get-Date).AddDays(-14).ToString("yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ssZ")
$endDate = (Get-Date).ToString("yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ssZ")

# Create an Azure DevOps REST API query to retrieve the deployment results
$queryUrl = "$baseUrl/_apis/release/deployments?definitionId=$pipelineId&$top=100&$expand=All&$filter=deploymentStatus eq 'succeeded' or deploymentStatus eq 'failed' and startedTime ge $startDate and startedTime le $endDate"
$headers = @{Authorization = "Bearer $pat"}

$response = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $queryUrl -Headers $headers -Method Get

# Create a new Excel workbook and worksheet
$excel = New-Object -ComObject Excel.Application
$workbook = $excel.Workbooks.Add()
$worksheet = $workbook.Worksheets.Add()

# Write the deployment results to the Excel worksheet
$row = 1
$col = 1
$worksheet.Cells.Item($row, $col) = "Stage"
$worksheet.Cells.Item($row, $col+1) = "Successful Count"
$worksheet.Cells.Item($row, $col+2) = "Failed Count"
$row++

foreach ($stageName in $stageNames) {
    $stageDeployments = $response.value | Where-Object {$_.releaseEnvironment.name -eq $stageName}
    $successfulCount = ($stageDeployments | Where-Object {$_.deploymentStatus -eq "succeeded"}).Count
    $failedCount = ($stageDeployments | Where-Object {$_.deploymentStatus -eq "failed"}).Count
    
    $worksheet.Cells.Item($row, $col) = $stageName
    $worksheet.Cells.Item($row, $col+1) = $successfulCount
    $worksheet.Cells.Item($row, $col+2) = $failedCount
    
    $row++
}

# Save the Excel workbook and close the Excel application
$workbook.SaveAs("DeploymentResults.xlsx")
$excel.Quit()
```

Comment: Fail Count should be zero.  You have one worksheet in the workbook.  So after script runs type $stagenames and see if the correct number of items are displayed.  If you are getting the correct number than one of the Where are failing.  If $stagenames is wrong than fix the names in $stagenames at beginning of script.

Comment: the script is not even detecting the stage names which i provided as a input in the above script...could someone please help what is wrong with above script...

Comment: You are making an HTTP request and getting bac a response.  Is response XML or JSON, or Text?  You stageNames have angle brackets.  So are you expecting XML?  You should parse the XML with a library instead of searching with Where.  Add in for loop for debugging : $stageName | Format-List

Answer (score 1):

I am able to get the stage names of a release defination/pipeline, but still unable to write the succcessful and failed count of deployments from each stage for a week data onto excel sheet.

```
# Define variables for the organization, project, and release definition ID
$organization = "<org name>"
$project = "<project name>"
$releaseDefinitionId = "<release defination ID>"

# Authenticate with Azure DevOps using a Personal Access Token (PAT)
$personalAccessToken = "<PAT>"
$base64AuthInfo = [Convert]::ToBase64String([Text.Encoding]::ASCII.GetBytes(":$($personalAccessToken)"))
$headers = @{Authorization = "Basic $base64AuthInfo"}

# Get the release definition by ID
$releaseDefinitionUrl = "https://vsrm.dev.azure.com/$($organization)/$($project)/_apis/release/definitions/$($releaseDefinitionId)?api-version=6.0"
$releaseDefinition = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $releaseDefinitionUrl -Headers $headers -Method Get

# Get the stage names from the release definition
$stageNames = $releaseDefinition.environments.name

# Output the stage names
Write-Host "Stage names:"
$stageNames
```